# How to hide Emoji keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hide the emoji keyboard when tapped outside of it. But it doesn't hide. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGqjV.png)

I have tried this code. It hides the text keyboard but not the emoji keyboard.

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus,
```

and for emoji keyboard

```
Offstage(
                offstage: !_showEmoji,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  child: EmojiPicker(
                    textEditingController: _textController,
                    config: Config(
                      bgColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      columns: 8,
                      emojiSizeMax: 32 * (Platform.isIOS ? 1.30 : 1.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a round about to this. You can make a bool for example `isShowingEmoji = false`, then you can set it to true while opening `EmojiPicker`, then in your `GestureDetector` you can use this code to unfocus it.

```
onTap:() {
    if(isShowingEmoji){
      Navigator.pop(context);
  } else {
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      }
    }
```

Note: there can be a good approach to this, this is just a round about.

Comment: It worked but I has to add parenthesis at the end of unfocus

Comment: Sorry my mistake, if it worked can you please  mark my answer as accepted ❤️

Answer (score -1):

oops, sorry it was wrong.

did you use EmojiPicker widget on the modal window like showModalBottomSheet? If not, I recommend using a modal window.

I think if you use EmojiPicker widget using a modal window, then GestureDetector onTap will work.

For example,

```
  ...
  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus,
      child: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30))),
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return EmojiPicker(
                    textEditingController: _textController,
                    config: Config(
                      bgColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      columns: 8,
                      // emojiSizeMax: 32 * (Platform.isIOS ? 1.30 : 1.0),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
          child: Text('Test')),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: That's literally the same thing